# Python bitmask doesn't give expected output

Tags: python, bitwise-operators, cocotb

Im puting a bitmask over a register read value and execute a logical and on the value. 
what i expect is:
`clear_reg_val: 00000000000000000100100000000000`
My actual output is:

```
# reg_value is:  00000000000000000100100000001100
# mask_inverted: 11111111111111111111100000000011
# clear_reg_val: 00000000000000000100100000001000
# reg_value is:  00000000000000000100100000001100
# mask_inverted: 11111111111111111111100000000011
# clear_reg_val: 00000000000000000100100000001000
```

So i don't know why bit 4 of clear_reg_val becomes a '1' instead of a '0'
The Python code of the function is added in the screenshot below:

[Python function for read modify write](https://i.stack.imgur.com/24bLP.png)

Comment: please post the code here, a screenshot is not OK

Comment: I'll do in future, for now my question is answered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is in the way you are creating the inverted mask.

You are doing it as a string operation, and converting the string back to an integer using `int`. You forgot to specify `base=2` and the string is treated as a decimal number.

The proper way to invert a 32 bit value is:

```
MASK32 = 2**32-1

invx = ~x & MASK32
```